# How do I proof that $\angle ABP =\angle AP'B$ and that $P$, $Q$, $Q'$ and $P'$ are on 1 circle?

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Given is a circle with center $M$ and a diameter $AB$. $k$ is the tangent to the circle at point $B$.

On the circle there are two points called $P$ and $Q$, such that $P$ and $Q$ are both on the same side of $AB$ and $Q$ is on the smallest arc between $B$ and $P$.
The intersection points of the lines with $AP$ and $AQ$ with $k$, are $P'$ and $Q'$.

[image]

Comment: Do you check which kind of triangle of ABP is?

Comment: ABP is a right-angled triangle since AB is the diameter.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same similarity as DonAntonia.

$180 - \angle Q'QP = \angle AQP = \angle ABP = \angle BP'A = \angle Q'P'P$.

$\implies \angle Q'QP$ and $\angle Q'P'P$ are supplementary.

As a result, $P,Q,P',Q'$ are concyclic.

Note: The transformation about $A$ that takes the circle with diametre $AB$ to the lines $P'Q'$ is called an inversion about $A$. Indeed, $AB^2 = AP \cdot AP' = AQ \cdot AQ'$ by the aforementioned similarity. So we define this map as taking a point $X$ to $X'$ so that $AX \cdot AX' = AB^2$. Notice that this means $AP \cdot AP' = AQ \cdot AQ'$, in turn giving the concyclic nature of $P,Q, P', Q'$, by power of a point.

Reading about inversion is interesting as it opens the world to Projective geometry :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that both $\;\Delta APB\;,\;\;\Delta ABP'\;$ are right triangles (why?), and they're similar since they have a common angle (which one?), and from similarity we get precisely 
$$\;\alpha:=\angle ABP=\angle AP'B\;$$

Now, a quadrilateral (say, $\;PP'Q'Q\;$) is circumscribed by a circle iff it has a pair of opposite angles that are supplementary (i.e., their sum is $\;180^\circ\;$ ).

Look at the trapezium $\;APQB\;$ . It is clearly an isosceles trapezium (why "clearly"?) , so $\;\alpha=\angle ABP=\angle BAQ=\angle BPQ\;$ (why?), and since $\;\Delta ABQ'\;$ is a right triangle (why?), we get that

$$\angle AQ'B=90^\circ-\alpha\implies\angle AQ'P'=90^\circ +\alpha$$

But we also have that

$$\angle QPP'=90^\circ-\alpha$$

and there: we're done.